# Laravel - Avoid Token missmatch exception on login when session as expired

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

When, in Laravel, you enter the page, it is created a session. This is the normal behavior of every page (not only Laravel). The case is that, it you stay in login page too much time withoout sending the form, you will receive a TokenMissmatchException because Session has refreshed and tokens are different.

We could handle the exception with a flash message saying something like "Session expired, try again". But I am triyng to get a better solution, I mean, when you submit the form, before sending it, renew the CSFR token someway and then submit the form with the refreshed token.

How can this be done without security issues?

Comment: What have you investigated/research so far?

Comment: I am googling but can't find so much info respect of this.